# OpenEJB can't start service cxf-rs with Null Pointer Exception

Tags: web-services, openejb

I'm trying to set up a simple proof of concept Rest service using a Stateless EJB bean deployed into OpenEJB.
I'm using openejb 4.6.0.2

```
Aug 04, 2015 4:14:15 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager start
INFO: Can't start service cxf-rs
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.deployApplication(RESTService.java:450)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:231)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:610)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.start(RESTService.java:898)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager.start(SimpleServiceManager.java:171)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ServiceManager.start(ServiceManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.Server.start(Server.java:95)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.Main.initServer(Main.java:157)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.Main.main(Main.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.cli.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:146)
    at org.apache.openejb.cli.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:105)
```

The null pointer is thrown on this call:

```
final RsRegistry.AddressInfo address = rsRegistry.createRsHttpListener(contextRoot, listener, classLoader, nopath.substring(NOPATH_PREFIX.length() - 1), virtualHost, auth, realm);
```

virtualHost, realm and auth all appear set in the openejb properties.
The contextRoot should default to the war name, is there a better place to set this specifically?

I'm not sure what else on here would throw a null pointer without causing bigger problems somewhere else in the container. The .war is deployed with no internal jars, just the rest bean and an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application.